# Dynamic VBO update possibly corrupting data?

Tags: opengl, java, glsl, vbo

I want to draw a line between two vertices.  On a mouseclick the vertex data will change and I want to update the line to use the new values.  I am using a VBO for this and it looks like the update process is somehow corrupting the VBO data.  The line is not drawing in a direction that I would expect given the values of the vertices.

There are four lines in total and I am updating only the last two vertices.  The vertex data is initialized as:

```
      float[] vertLineBuffer = {
          1.0f,0.0f,0.0f,//right
          0.0f,1.0f,0.0f,//top
          0.0f,0.0f,0.0f, //center
          -1.0f,0.0f,0.0f, //START
          0.0f,-1.0f,0.0f //END
            };
```

**The init routine:**

```
  public void setLineVBOs(GL4 gl)  throws Exception {

      vboLineHandles = new int[2];
      gl.glGenBuffers(2, vboLineHandles, 0);


      //populate the position buffer
      FloatBuffer fbData = Buffers.newDirectFloatBuffer(vertLineBuffer);
      gl.glBindBuffer(GL4.GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, vboLineHandles[VERTICES_LINE_IDX]); //the vertex data
      gl.glBufferData(GL4.GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, fbData.capacity() * 4, 
              fbData, GL4.GL_STATIC_DRAW);
      fbData.clear(); //don't need this anymore  

      //populate the color buffer
      FloatBuffer fbColor = Buffers.newDirectFloatBuffer(vertLineColor);
      gl.glBindBuffer(GL4.GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, vboLineHandles[VERTICES_LINECOLOR_IDX]); //the vertex data
      gl.glBufferData(GL4.GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, fbColor.capacity() * 4, 
              fbColor, GL4.GL_STATIC_DRAW);
      fbColor.clear(); //don't need this anymore  

      //set vertex array index
      IntBuffer intBuffer = BufferUtil.newIntBuffer(1);
      gl.glGenVertexArrays(1, intBuffer);
      iLineVao = intBuffer.get(0);
      gl.glBindVertexArray(iLineVao);

      gl.glEnableVertexAttribArray(VERTICES_LINE_IDX);
      gl.glEnableVertexAttribArray(VERTICES_LINECOLOR_IDX);

      gl.glBindBuffer(GL4.GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, vboLineHandles[VERTICES_LINE_IDX]); //the vertex data
      // Associate Vertex attribute 1 with the last bound VBO
      gl.glVertexAttribPointer(0,3, GL2ES2.GL_FLOAT, false,0,0);

      //color
      gl.glBindBuffer(GL4.GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, vboLineHandles[VERTICES_LINECOLOR_IDX]); //the vertex data
      gl.glVertexAttribPointer(1,3, GL2ES2.GL_FLOAT, false,0,0);

  }
```

**And then I attempt to update the VBO on an event (mouseclick) like this:**

```
  public void updateLine(GL4 gl, float[] pos)
  {
      //pos contains the new vertex data
      vertLineBuffer[9] = pos[0];
      vertLineBuffer[10] = pos[1];
      vertLineBuffer[11] = pos[2];
      vertLineBuffer[12] = pos[3];
      vertLineBuffer[13] = pos[4];
      vertLineBuffer[14] = pos[5]; 

      FloatBuffer fbData = Buffers.newDirectFloatBuffer(vertLineBuffer);

      gl.glBufferSubData(GL4.GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, 0, fbData.capacity() * 4, fbData);
      gl.glBindBuffer(GL4.GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, vboLineHandles[VERTICES_LINE_IDX]); 

      fbData.clear(); 

  }
```

**The vertex shader:**

```
#version 430

layout (location=0) in vec3 vertexPosition;
layout (location=1) in vec3 vertexColor;

out vec3 Color;

void main(void) {
    Color = vertexColor; 
    gl_Position = vec4(vertexPosition, 1.0);
}
```

**The frag shader:**

```
#version 430

in vec3 Color;

layout (location = 0) out vec4 FragColor;

void main(void) {

    FragColor = vec4(Color, 1.0); 

}
```

Does this look right?  Can anyone see where this might damage the contents of the VBO?

Comment: You're calling glBufferSubData before you've bound your buffer.

Comment: I know, I had it the other way originally and strangely enough it makes no difference, visually,  if I bind before or after glBufferSubData.